# How do i remove the first row of the header of a dataframe and change the heading name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a function to return data that contains a Panda DataFrame like below

```
                                 RSI
Date                                
2023-10-02 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-03 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-04 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-05 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-06 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-09 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-10 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-11 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-12 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-13 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-16 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-17 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-18 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-19 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-20 00:00:00+11:00  47.058827
2023-10-23 00:00:00+11:00  50.212766
2023-10-24 00:00:00+11:00  47.185484
2023-10-25 00:00:00+11:00  44.308668
2023-10-26 00:00:00+11:00  44.308668
2023-10-27 00:00:00+11:00  44.308668
2023-10-30 00:00:00+11:00  44.308668
```

I want to remove the first row of the header and add the heading name on the second column to "RSI" like below. I have googled a lot, trying to use df.iloc[0], etc but with no success.

```
Date                             RSI  
2023-10-02 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-03 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-04 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-05 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-06 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-09 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-10 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-11 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-12 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-13 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-16 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-17 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-18 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-19 00:00:00+11:00        NaN
2023-10-20 00:00:00+11:00  47.058827
2023-10-23 00:00:00+11:00  50.212766
2023-10-24 00:00:00+11:00  47.185484
2023-10-25 00:00:00+11:00  44.308668
2023-10-26 00:00:00+11:00  44.308668
2023-10-27 00:00:00+11:00  44.308668
2023-10-30 00:00:00+11:00  44.308668
```

The following is my codes:

```
rsiData = getRSI(asx_stock)
print("rsiData type:", type(rsiData))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=rsiData)
print(df)
monthly_rsiData_html = Markup(df.to_html())
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue that would be much appreciated? Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like you're looking for [`df.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Comment: Just reset the index of the DataFrame so that "Date" becomes a column, and then rename the columns appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pandas use the date as index. Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=rsiData, columns=['Date', 'RSI'])
```

else, as @Nick suggested in the comments: `df.reset_index()`